# Retag request: change [sharedfolders] to [shared-folders]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Retagging a question on SF, I noticed the tag [sharedfolders](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sharedfolders), and it should have a hyphen in between, as they are two separate words, right?

Can we retag all [sharedfolders](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sharedfolders) to [shared-folders](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/shared-folders)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done (+ tag synonym created.)

Comment: @studiohack Thanks for asking and thanks for all your work (flagging posts) here on SF! We (moderators) appreciate it very much.

Comment: no problem, glad to help! I'm a ♦ over on SU, so I know what needs to be done :)